# How can I insert multiple emails in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to insert multiple emails of a user into a different table in Laravel.
Is it possible?

Here is code:

```
use App\PersonData;

class PersonDataController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new PersonData();

        return PersonData::store($request->person_data,$user);
    }
}
```

here is model

```
 use App\CustomerEmail;
 use App\SupplierEmail;

 class PersonData extends Model
 {
     public function customeremails()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(CustomerEmail::class);
     }

     public function supplieremails()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(SupplierEmail::class);
     }

     public static function store($request,$user)
     {
         $user = fill($request);
         $user->save();

         return $user;

     }
}
```

here is 2nd model where want to insert multiple emails

```
class CustomerEmail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['emails','person_data_id'];

    public function persondata()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PersonData::class);
    }
}
```

and final json code

```
{
  "person_data": {
    "first_name": "Customer",
    "last_name": "customer_lastname",
    "company_name": "new industry",
    "gst_number": "no",
    "type": "customer",
    "customeremails": [
      {
        "person_data": 1,
        "email": "relation@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "address": "house 123, city:ludhiana",
    "phone_numbers": "8844845545",
    "website": "www.google.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear.. Can you please elaborate in which table, you want to insert multiple emails? Also, add the route for the same.

Comment: i want to insert persondata(user) multiple emails into CustomereEmail with user_id
and data return in array form and i dont know how to insert array values into table

Comment: Provide the route and the responsible controller method as well.. There's hardly anyone who would do the 'Homework' for you. Your question just says How it is to be done while you have not disclosed What have you done so far. Hence, the word 'Homework'.

Comment: problem is now i cant my edit question
here is route 
$api->version('v1', function($api){
  
  $api->post('customer/store','App\Http\Controllers\PersonDataController@store');
  $api->post('supplier/store','App\Http\Controllers\PersonDataController@store');
 });

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question. what you are looking for is `saveMany()` function for a `one-to-many` relationship.

**or may be i misunderstood your question**

```
// first gather all the emails to be saved after 'person data' is saved.
// because 'customer email' needs 'person data' id.
$customer_emails = collect();

foreach($request->person_data->customeremails as $email) {

    $cutomer_email = CustomerEmail::make([
        'email' => $email.email
    ]);

    $customer_emails->push($customer_email);
}

// save 'person data' first
$person_data = PersonData::create([
    // your person_data
]);

// this will automatically set 'person_data' foreign key on the 'customer email' table
// and save
$person_data->customeremails()->savemany($customer_emails);
```

Comment: Thanks sir i tried(savemany) and post result 
but where i gather all emails before bcoz all things happen in one click on same form

Comment: so that means, your posted json result on the question is not your expected json result?

Comment: yes sir......... its api where i hit to submit :)
now problem is cant edit question bcz of plenty mistakes i a have done

Comment: thanks problem solved with foreach method and relationship with associate method